# Conversão de Celsius e Farenheit

Tags: python

Criei uma função para converter graus celsius em farenheit. No entanto, não consigo execultá-la ao atribuir valores, como por exemplo, transformar 30°c em 86°F. Não retorna nenhum valor, já tentei de tudo e nada acontece. Gostaria de encarecidamente pedir ajuda, pois ainda sou iniciante em python.

```
# crie sua função conveterCelsius (x)
def celsius_fahrenheit (): 
  c = float(input ('Digite a temperatura em °c'))
  f = float ((9*c)/5) + 32 

  return ('A temperatura em fahrenheit: {0}°f'.format (f))
```

Quando tento atribuir valores nada acontece:

```
# Testando valores de c
def celsius_fahrenheit (): 
  c = (30)
  f = ((9*c)/5) + 32
  return ('A temperatura em fahrenheit: {0}°f'.format (f))
```

Comment: faltou algo como um `print celsius_farhenheit()` chamando a função (que tem dois objetivos: o primeiro é executar a função que foi definida, senão ela fica à sua disposição, mas não executa, e o segundo objetivo, com o print, é mostrar o resultado). Ainda para uma melhor organização do código, você pode fazer um `def celsius_fahrenheit(c)` e passar o valor do input na chamada, assim podendo reaproveitar a função independente do jeito que o valor é obtido.

Answer (score 0):

Maria Clara, acrescentei no seu código uma função print no return da sua função. Verifique no seu código que se a indentação do seu código está correta também. Segue o código para comparação:

```
def celsius_fahrenheit():
   c = float(input('Digite a temperatura em °c'))
   f = float((9 * c) / 5) + 32

   return print('A temperatura em fahrenheit: {0}°F'.format(f))

celsius_fahrenheit()
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).